# Pass data from activity 1 to activity 2 and calculate the given data in a function

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I need to have an button on the main acitivity which takes a few variables (double) and pass them to the second activity in which the given data is used in a function to measure your daily calorie-need. Is here a nice fella who has an example code or could help me with this topic? Im programming with java in android studio.
My current code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/7gxK4VYZ

Comment: people are willing to help if you show what you've done, but this isn't a free coding/homework service and your question has a lot of simple components to it. what have you done so far ? please post your code

Comment: you right, i dont ask often questions here and when i try to put the code in the code section it wont be formated as code

Comment: @a_local_nobody you have a good point

Comment: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2091465/208273)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intent` to send the data from the first `Activity` to another one like this:

*In the first activity*

**Step 1** Add this code on button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("value", oneValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

*In the second activity*

**Step 2** Create a variable:

```
String anotherValue;
```

**Step 3** Init this variable:

```
anotherValue = getIntent().getStringExtras("value");
```

Now the value from your first activity is stored in the variable `anotherValue and you can use it in any method of the second activity.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite simple to do, but as a new programmer, I can understand that it can be challenging at times. Here is what I would do.

Lets say your button function is called "passData()" and your getting these values from the user from the first screen and storing them in valOne and valTwo.

do this:

```
public void passData(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("valueOne", valOne);
    intent.putExtra("valueTwo", valTwo);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

in your second activity, do this:

```
        //Get the text view
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //Get the values from previous screen
        getValOne = getIntent().getStringExtra("valueOne");
        getValTwo = getIntent().getStringExtra("valueTwo");

        //Convert to int to use in function
        int intValOne = Integer.parseInt(getValOne);
        int intValTwo = Integer.parseInt(getValTwo);

        //Insert in your function
        int x = intValOne + intValTwo;
        result.setText(x);
```

*** getValOne and getValTwo have been declared globally. ***

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to pass data from one activity (MainActivity) to another activity (SecondActivity):

**MainActivity**

```
String yourData = "My Data";

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA", yourData);
startActivity(intent);
```

then in SecondActivity you should set this to take the data

**SecondActivity**

```
String myData = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_DATA");
```

**Another Example**
If you have 2 data you can try this

```
String name = "Sangkuni";
String gender = "Male";

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA_NAME", name);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA_GENDER", gender);
startActivity(intent);
```

then in SecondActivity

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_DATA_NAME");
String gender = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_DATA_GENDER");
```

I hope my answer will help you